# Dynamic WSO2 API manager store theme change

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I need to change WSO2 API manager store theme dynamically based on the inbound request.

For example customer1 should be able to access store with theme specific to customer1.
customer2 should be able to access store with theme specific to customer2.

Is it possible with WSO2 APIM ?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, The API Store theme cannot be changed according to the user who login in. The theme is applied node wise. If you have a clustered/multiple store setup you can have different themese for each API store.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme

Comment: Even it's not supported out of the box. Actually I found a workaround to dynamically change themes by duplicating store jaggery app and changing the context url for each customer. By limiting api visibility based on user role it's a good enough workaround for my usecase. May be I'll write a blog on it later on.
Thanks anyway